# How manage error of xmlReadMemory (libxml Gnome) in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: libxml2, gnome

I use the libxml2 Gnome in a multithreaded environment.
When I call xmlReadMemory() I use xmlGetLastError() to have the detail of error message.
However this function, according to the doc, returns the last global error registered and it is per thread. So I will have concurrency issues in a multithreaded environment.

```
res = xmlReadMemory(document, len, "test", NULL, 0);
xmlErrorPtr pErr = xmlGetLastError();
printf("pErr %s", pErr->message)
```

**So how get safely the detail of the error of xmlReadMemory() in a multithreaded environment?
**

Answer (score 0):

The error variable being per thread means that `xmlGetLastError` is thread-safe. (As long as libxml2 is compiled with thread support but this should be the default.)